# WooCommerce: what hook AFTER order is saved/updated from ANY context

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I'm creating a module that would send orders data to third party services so I'm trying to find a hook that would be fired AFTER the woocommerce shop order is saved/updated from ANY context: when the order was just created, when the order status changed, when the order delivery details were changed from admin panel, etc.

What I found so far and why it's not what I need:

`woocommerce_order_status_changed` - triggers only when status is changed

`woocommerce_saved_order_items` - triggers BEFORE the data is updated (at least on admin panel the older order data is sent)

`save_post_shop_order` - the same as previous

`woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` - also the same

`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` - triggers only on checkout

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution - using `woocommerce_after_order_object_save`, but as for now the function is a bit broken - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/25771

And the usage is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_object_save', 'some_order_action', 10, 1 );
function some_order_action( $order ) {
  ...
}
```

Better solutions are welcome!

Comment: Also woocommerce_after_order_object_save seems to trigger before status change, so it also doesn't work for me. And the correct data is sent just because it is sent multiple times, meaning the first time the old data is sent.