# Woocommerce action after an order is saved with code (not checkout)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I import orders from Shopify into Wordpress using a plugin, it works fine the orders are created. I'm using the Shopify API to import data from the order Timeline, since the sync plugin isn't capable of doing that on its own. But I need the Shopify ID to import the correct Timeline data, which is stored by the sync plugin as order meta data.

I'm using the action save_post_shop_order which fires every time a new order is imported from Shopify. The problem is, it fires before the meta data is saved, which means the Shopify_ID meta data is always empty, failing to import the Timeline data. If I save the order again, it works fine and imports the Timeline data correctly. save_post_shop_order fires again when an order is saved, and the Shopify_ID meta is available at that point, so it works when saving an already existing order, but not when the Order is first added.

I want a Woocommerce action that fires -after- the Order meta is stored. Some actions to consider:
woocommerce_thankyou : won't work since there is no checkout involved
save_post_shop_order : doesn't work because it's fired before meta is saved in an order
woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta : there is no checkout, order is created with code
woocommerce_saved_order_items : triggers before meta is saved

From reading this post: [WooCommerce: what hook AFTER order is saved/updated from ANY context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386282/woocommerce-what-hook-after-order-is-saved-updated-from-any-context)
I tried using woocommerce_after_order_object_save but that caused a memory overflow, not sure why that happened. Plus it appears to be called on every object change.

Any suggestions?

Edit
The sequence of events:

1. An order is made in Shopify
2. Plugin gets the Order and transfers it to Woocommerce
3. Order is created in Woocommerce by the plugin
4. save_post_shop_order action hook is triggered, but the meta data required (Shopify_ID) is not yet saved, only the rest of the Order data
5. I try to get Timeline data for that Order but fails because the Shopify ID isn't valid
6. After save_post_shop_order is finished, the order is saved WITH the Shopify_ID as well

I want to find an action that executes -after- step 6, because what I've tried is fired either at step 4, or at checkout (I have no checkout)

Comment: Call `$order->update_meta_data($meta['key'], $meta['value']);` before `$order->save();`

Comment: update_meta_data requires the value to be known already which I don't have access to when save_post_shop_order is called. Unless you are suggesting I make to the plugin itself where it saves the order, which could work but would cause issues with updating (it's a commercial plugin)

Comment: There will be filters available in that plugin before saving. That will be the best way rather hooking on save_post